# Keydown is not working

Tags: android

hi i wanted to populate one text box from the input of other text box on every key press but this is not happening. the code is like this

```
leftside.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) 
        {
            if(arg2.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                Log.v("keyevent", "down");
                float value = Float.parseFloat(leftside.getText().toString());
                rightside.setText(String.valueOf(SelectConverter(Float.parseFloat(leftside.getText().toString()))));
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: is the method onKey called anyway?

Comment: and is "down" visible in logcat?

Comment: also, note that you should return true, if the listener has consumed the event

Comment: yes fucntion called once when i press delete or backspace

Comment: yes "down" in logcat because i am capturing action_down

Comment: try action_up  
because on action_down maybe the text is not updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hi i wanted to populate one text box from the input of other text box
>   on every key press but this is not happening. the code is like this

I suggest to you use `TextChangedListener` with `TextWatcher` instead of `KeyListener`. I think it is more suitable to use to reach your goal and work with it is more comfortable.

Here is example:

- [`Android EditText text change listener
  example`](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-text-change-listener.html)